# Data is lost after merging selected features and pressing save

Tags: qgis

I've run into this problem multiple times. I'll merge features and the data will appear. Then when I hit the save button, all my merged data are replaced with null.

This is in QGIS 2.14.1

Comment: Do you mean data fields will have null values and not features disappearing? More details about what you are doing may help identify the problem

Comment: Are you working with shape, Spatialite or PostGIS?

Comment: Are both fields from both features the same datatype and length?